# How to display the docker current configuration?

Tags: docker

I have installed the docker daemon on a Debian 8 machine. And after setting a value for "DOCKER_OPTS" within the file "/etc/default/docker" I wanted to check if 
after restarting the service the value was set properly.

Is there a command to display the current docker's configuration ?

Comment: `ps aux | grep docker`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some researches I found the following issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9889 which explains that systemd ignores the configuration file `/etc/default/docker`. Therefore in my case "DOCKER_OPTS" is not set.

After editing the file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` it is possible to check that the value is set correctly with the command, mentioned by Adrian, `ps aux | grep docker`.

The other useful commands to check the installation version and system information are `docker version` and `docker info`.

Comment: I had a similar question (how to get the current value of the Insecure Registries setting) and the `docker info` command worked for this.

Comment: There should be a command like `docker info` that shows whatever is configured for the docker engine daemon at the time. I want a way to validate settings (not that they are present in a configuration file or environment variable).

Comment: I want to print the `log-driver` and `log-opts` values from /etc/docker/daemon.json to ensure they took. docker info shows the driver but not the opts. Which, means I would have to wait and monitor for a threshold to hit to ensure the settings took, `ls -lha /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*json.log`.